# how to check if a user input already exists in a text file within c#

Tags: c#, text-files

i am making a c# application for my a a level computing coursework. my coursework requires me to have a registration and login  system and i am currently stuck with the registration part because my registration system is meant to check if a username chosen by the user already exists within the text file.

i have already searched on stack overflow on a solution and have tried to implement similar solutions bu it dosent seem to work as my code still lets new users to register with an already existing password

```
 string firstname = txtBoxFirstname.Text;
 string surname = txtBoxSurname.Text;
 string fullname = txtBoxFirstname.Text+" "+txtBoxSurname.Text;
 string username = txtBoxUsername.Text;
 string password = txtBoxPassword.Text;
 string confirmedPassword = txtBoxConfirmedPassword.Text;
 DateTime lastlogin = DateTime.Now;
 bool containsUser = File.ReadLines("users.txt").Contains(username);

if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname)) && 
   ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(surname)) && 
   ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) && 
   (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) && 
   (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(confirmedPassword)))))
{

    if ((!username.Contains("~")) || (!password.Contains("~")))
    {
        if (password == confirmedPassword)
        {
            if (containsUser == false)//this is the part that check if a username already exists
            {
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("users.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                try
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(fullname + "~" + username + "~" + password + "~" + lastlogin);

                    MessageBox.Show("User registered successfully", "Registration Successful");

                    this.Hide();
                    var homeForm = new HomeForm();
                    homeForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
                    homeForm.Show();

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error registering the user", "Please try again");
                }
                finally
                {
                    streamWriter.Close();
                    fileStream.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry this username is already taken", "Please try again");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Passwords must match",
                        "Incorrect Details");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Username and password must not contain any special characters i.e. ~", "~ entered");
    }

}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please ensure all data is entered into the fields",
        "Details missing");
}
```

my expected code should return a message saying that this username is already taken if the username entered already exists but my program still creates the user an account anyway

Comment: Side note: take a look at [Arrow Code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/)

Comment: So did you debug? What is the value of containsUser?

Comment: Difficult to say without debugging it, but are the users all in the same case (username1 != Username1).  My advice would be to separate the part of your logic that checks for the username inside the text and put that in a separate function (pass the string in) and then write a unit test.  That should help you to determine what the issue is quickly.

Comment: Could read text file and grab all `usernames` from file and put it into a `list`, check new `username` against `list`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner that will check whether your file contains the username:

```
bool usernameExists = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\path\to\your\file.txt").Contains("~" + username + "~");
```

The reason why your program registers new users all the time is because you made a slight logic error in the use of `ReadLines()` - it returns an array of strings. If your file has 3 lines:

```
John smith~john~password1
Jane smith~jane~password2
Fred smith~fred~password3
```

That's what you get as an array, as if you'd done this in code:

```
var array = new string[3];
array[0] = "John smith~john~password1";
array[1] = "Jane smith~jane~password2";
array[2] = "Fred smith~fred~password3";
```

Then if you ask an entire array if it `.Contains()` the username, it will only respond true if one of the strings inside the array is exactly "john".

This array doesn't have a string that is exactly "john", though one of those lines does have within it the text "john".. But when you use `.Contains()` on an array of string it will only return true if one of the strings in the array is equal to "john"

None of your strings in your array is equal to John

If you'd said:

```
File.ReadLines(...).Contains("John smith~john~password1");
```

then the result would be true, because one of the strings in the array really is equal to "John smith~john~password1".

Alternatively, if you'd looped through the array of strings and asked each string if it cointains "john" within it:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(...);
foreach(string line in lines)
  if(line.Contains("~" + username + "~"))
    contains = true;
```

this also would have worked out.

TLDR:

- ArrayOfString.Contains("john") --> checks whenther one of the strings in the array is equal to the string "john"
- ASingleString.Contains("john") --> checks whether the single string has "john" somewhere within it

Possibly confusing, i know, that both Array and String classes both have a method called Contains, but it happens a lot - same name, different behavior

---

The reason why the ReadAllText() works out is that it just gives you the file as one long string. Your usernames always have a ~ either side of them, so a string of `John smith~john~password1\r\nJane smith~jane~password2\r\nFred smith~fred~password3` does indeed contain `~john~`

There's a slight bug potential with this: if one of the passwords is "john" this way will also return true. Of course, you're going to be hashing your passwords so they can't be read, for security right? ;) but it's a risk to be aware of and deal with as appropriate (later)

---

I'd be tempted to use `File.AppendAllText` to add your usernames to your file rather than the way you've done it: it's a one line method that opens the file, writes to it and closes it again.

You might want to get more sophisticated than my File.ReadAllText, and go for your method, but remember to treat the array of strings properly:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(...);
foreach(string line in lines){
  string[] bits = line.Split('~');
  string fullname = bits[0];
  string username = bits[1];
  string password = bits[2];
  string lastlogin= bits[3];

  //now you can do more thorough checks
  if(userinput.Equals(username, InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) //case insensitive compare
}
```

Splitting the string on ~ into its components is a more reliable way of checking your data, it will help later with checking they typed the right password, returning their full name for the welcome message etc..

Comment: `Contains("~" + username + "~")` will not work, because someone could use password which equals given username.

Comment: Yes, I've covered that

Answer (score 0):

Here you check whether a file contains a line which **exactly** matches user name

```
File.ReadLines("users.txt").Contains(username)
```

But your lines look like `fullname + "~" + username + "~" + password + "~" + lastlogin` and of course there never will be a line which maches `username`. What you should do is splitting each line on the separator symbol you are using (`~`) and getting user name from it:

```
var registeredUsers =
      from line in File.ReadLines("users.txt")
      let parts = line.Split('~')
      select parts[1]; // because first goes full name

bool containsUser = registeredUsers.Contains(username);
```

---

Few notes:

- Keeping passwords is a bad idea - you should store password hashes instead.
- Consider using a database to avoid parsing all users data each time your users are logged in or registered
- Consider using Guard Conditions to avoid Arrow Code antipattern
- Consider separating UI code, business logic, and persistence-related code. It will simplify your programs a lot. E.g. in this case you can have `UserRepository` which knows how to hidrate users from storage, `UserService` which is responsible for business logic (e.g. checking if username already in use before registering new user), and UI code which is responsible for getting data from controls and displaying results to user (it should call service to get results).

Comment: Considering the audience, I didn't think using LINQ to be particularly appropriate. I'd also extend this "sense of what is suited to the audience" to most of your bullet points..

Comment: Considering the fact that the 'audience' is already used LINQ I don't see any reasons to move away from it. Also, SO is not only for the person who asks the question - anyone who reads the answers is the 'audience'. You, for example.